# Error creating bean with name 'dietaController'

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-jpa

я изучаю spring boot и имею таку проблему: когда  я запускаю приложение , то выскакивает такая ошибка :

```
2020-01-31 00:54:29.318 ERROR 7212 --- [main] o.s.boot.SpringApplication: Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'dietaController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'dietaRepository'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'dietaRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Not a managed type: class com.diet4you.LapkoEkaterina.Dieta
```

Мой pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>org.diet4you</groupId>
    <artifactId>LapkoEkaterina</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>

    </parent>
    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.boot/spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
                    <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/mysql/mysql-connector-java -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
            <version>5.2.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.0.16.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
            <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>

        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Сущность Dieta:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "diety")
public class Dieta {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy= GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name="DIETA_ID") 
    private int dietaId;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(unique=true, name ="DIETA_NAZWA")
    private String nazwa;

    @NotEmpty
    @Column(name="OPIS") 
    private String opis;

    public Dieta(){ }

    public Dieta (int dietaId,String nazwa, String opis ){ 
        this.dietaId = dietaId;
        this.nazwa = nazwa;
        this.opis = opis;
    }

    public int getDietaId() {
        return dietaId; 
    }

    public void setDietaId(int dietaId) {
        this.dietaId = dietaId; 
    }

    public String getNazwa() {
        return nazwa; 
    }

    public void setNazwa(String nazwa) {
        this.nazwa = nazwa; 
    }

    public String getOpis() {
        return opis; 
    }

    public void setOpis(String opis) {
        this.opis = opis; 
    }
}
```

Репозиторий:

```
@Repository
public interface DietaRepository extends JpaRepository<Dieta, String> {
    Dieta findByName (String name);
}
```

Контроллер:

```
@RestController
public class DietaController {
    @Autowired
    private DietaRepository dietaRepository;
    @GetMapping("/dieta")
    public List<Dieta> getAllNotes() {
        return dietaRepository.findAll();
    }

}
```

Класс приложения:

```
@Configuration
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableJpaRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "com.diet4you.LapkoEkaterina")
@EntityScan ( basePackages  = { " com.diet4you.LapkoEkaterina" })
public class Application {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: В будущем, пожалуйста, прикладывайте нормально отформатированный код.

Comment: Спасибо!.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1) Удалите случайный (наверное) пробел в `@EntityScan ( basePackages  = { " com.diet4you.LapkoEkaterina" })`

Должно быть так: `@EntityScan ( basePackages  = { "com.diet4you.LapkoEkaterina" })`

Это решит проблему номер один.

---

2) Вы когда расширяете свой репозиторий `extends JpaRepository<Dieta, String>` вторым параметром подставляете объект типа **String**, но радость в том, что второй параметр должен принимать тип идентификатора вашей сущности.

В вашем же случае вы указали идентификатором сущности **Dieta** поле `private int dietaId`.

Значит вам нужно указать **Integer**. Соответственно ваше расширение репозитория должно быть таковым: `extends JpaRepository<Dieta, Integer>`

---

3) Уберите или исправьте `Dieta findByName (String name);`, это неверно и вызовет ошибку на старте приложения.

Comment: Спасибо, что заметили ошибку, к сожалению, это не решает проблему выше

Comment: @lapka1002 тогда уберите галку с ответа, а в ваш вопрос приложите полный лог

Comment: @lapka1002 исправил ответ, выполните эти рекомендации и сообщите результат

Comment: Помогло изменение репозитория , спасибо !)